# MongoDB $sort not giving expected results

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I am trying to sort the results from the $group stage, they seems not in the expected order.
Any help is appreciated!

**Query1:**

`db.schools.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,School_Name:1}},{$group:{_id:"$School_Name"}},{$sort:{School_Name:1}}])`
**Result:**

```
{ "_id" : "Beulah Junior School" }
{ "_id" : "Archbishop Tenison's CofE High School" }
{ "_id" : "Norbury Manor Business and Enterprise College for Girls" }
{ "_id" : "St Joseph's RC Junior School" }
{ "_id" : "Harris Invictus Academy Croydon" }
{ "_id" : "Selsdon Primary and Nursery School" }
{ "_id" : "The Crescent Primary School" }
{ "_id" : "John Ruskin College" }
{ "_id" : "Al-Khair School" }

Type "it" for more
```

**Query2:**

`> db.schools.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,School_Name:1,school_lc:{$toLower:"$School_Name"}}},{$group:{_id:"$school_lc"}},{$sort:{school_lc:1}}])`

**Result:**

```
 { "_id" : "downsview primary and nursery school" }
    { "_id" : "orchard way primary school" }
    { "_id" : "aerodrome primary academy" }
    { "_id" : "krishna avanti primary school" }
    { "_id" : "riddlesdown collegiate" }
    { "_id" : "kingsley primary academy" }
    { "_id" : "royal russell school" }
    { "_id" : "good shepherd catholic primary and nursery school" }

Type "it" for more
```

Answer (score 0):

The $group resulting records do not have 'School_Name' field, that's why $sort on 'School_Name' not working.

Try to sort on _id,

```
db.schools.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,School_Name:1}},{$group:{_id:"$School_Name"}},{$sort:{_id:1}}])
```

**Result:**

```
{"_id" : "Al-Khair School"}
{"_id" : "Archbishop Tenison's CofE High School"}
{"_id" : "Beulah Junior School"}
{"_id" : "Harris Invictus Academy Croydon"}
{"_id" : "John Ruskin College"}
{"_id" : "Norbury Manor Business and Enterprise College for Girls"}
{"_id" : "Selsdon Primary and Nursery School"}
{"_id" : "St Joseph's RC Junior School"}
{"_id" : "The Crescent Primary School"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  db.schools.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$School_Name"}},{$sort:{_id:1}}])
```